# About Linux Auditd log

Tags: c, linux

In audit.log, I can see:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1646113477.615:531): arch=c000003e syscall=3 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=7ffcadf66ae0 a2=7ffcadf66b60 a3=8 items=0 ppid=1431 pid=1451 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=19 comm="bash" exe="/bin/bash" key=(null)
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1646113477.615:531): proctitle="-bash"
```

The question is: How can I get the closed file name?

Comment: May be looking at the configuration in /etc/audit/auditd.conf could help ?

Comment: you should ask this over at Server Fault